# Error when try to install KVM on CentOS

Tags: centos, kvm

I am trying to install KVM from [Installation doc](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/liaai/kvminstall/liaaikvminstallstart.htm).

When I run the command `modprobe kvm-intel` I get the error `FATAL: Error inserting kvm_intel (/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko): Operation not supported`.

I also run the `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and output is as below.

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 2494.420
cache size      : 3072 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc up arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts
bogomips        : 4988.84
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

May be I am missing some command but which I don't know :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your Intel chipset isn't supported. You don't have an Intel VT chipset (no vmx flag in your `/proc/cpuinfo`), so you can't run KVM on your machine. From the [KVM FAQ](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/topic/liaat/liaatkvmfaq.htm):

> Q:    How do I know if my hardware supports KVM?
>
> A:    Run the following
>   command:
>
> ```
>  
> grep -E 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo
> flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat
> pse36 clflush dts
> acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts
> pni monitor ds_cpl vmx
> est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm ida
> flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat
> pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr
> sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni monitor
> ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm ida
> ```
>
> If this command returns output, then your system supports KVM. The vmx
>   processor feature flag represents Intel VT chipset while the svm flag
>   represents AMD-V.

Comment: He can still virtualize via qemu, but it will be slower.

Answer (score 3):

There may be hope yet, some BIOS versions mask the bit when disabling virtualization extensions so it does not appear in procinfo.

I would try to enable VT in the BIOS, then disconnect the power cord (it's a requirement), if it's a laptop you may have to take the battery out and put it back in as well.

Afterwards when you boot, check again. As I said, only some versions do this so you may still fail, but it's worth a try.

Checking your processor model number indicates that it does support VT-d [(specs)](http://processors.findthebest.com/l/21/Intel-i5-2520M), though the chipset may not support it and make it unavailable.

Comment: +1.  also, enabling virtualisation can often be hidden in a really bizarre location in the BIOS (esp. on name-brand PCs like HP).  e.g. on a HP dc7800 (with Intel Core2 Quad Q9450 CPU), it was hidden away in "Security Settings" (or something like that, I can't remember the exact text of the menu item).  It would never have occurred to me to look in a security menu for virtualisation options, I only found it by exhaustive search of ALL menu items out of desperation.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply, but checked in BIOS and its virtualisation enabled. I am also running VMware on this. I have HP EliteBook 8460p. I also tried after removing the battery and check `grep -E 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo` but output is same :(.

Comment: So you have no choice but to get a new motherboard or use a software virtualization like virtualbox, vmware , zen or qemu.
@CraigSanders it is a security feature to avoid a virtualization based rootkit

Comment: @David: that's like saying the power switch is a security feature to avoid a code-based rootkit.  By that reasoning, all features which can be enabled/disabled/configured in the bios belong under the security menu.

Comment: @CraigSanders, not at all, there are 3 main features that are defined as security in the hardware - Virtualization, NoExecute memory regions, and "beacon" that is active in some Intel CPUs.

We're digressing here, you are welcome to post a question about this in the security stackexchange site, you're welcome to tag me so I'd know about it.

Comment: i don't need to ask a question about it and i certainly don't need to be patronised.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo.
```

For Intel cpu  is vmx flag.

http://ark.intel.com/products/52229/
   Intel indicates your cpu  i5-2520M supports vmx. So your bios has this this feature switched off! Just open it in your bios!

Answer (score 1):

check the BIOS configuration of your computer, turn on Intel VT if it is OFF. https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/iss/proliant-gen10-uefi/s_enabling_virtual_tech.html